# MYSQL: get data that have similar column

Tags: mysql

I have this in my database:

```
id | column1
1 | ab
2 | cd
3 | cd
4 | ef
5 | cd
6 | ab
```

And I would like to get either ids :(1,6) or (2,3,5) or (4) but it has to have the same column1 name

I don't have a specific column1 name to search.

I want something that does the same thing as:

```
row=SELECT column1 FROM table LIMIT 1
row2=SELECT id FROM table WHERE column1=row[0].column1
```

but in one query, is that possible?

Comment: Please provide more detail ....
do you want get id's of column1 match?
or some thing other else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest SQL queries

`row= SELECT id 
 FROM table 
 WHERE column1=(SELECT column1 FROM table LIMIT 1)`

Comment: I guess @Theo Z clearly mentioned that column1 name is not available.

Comment: To be honest, it isnt all that clear. He says it isnt available, then uses it in his example. Either way, this is the functionality he's looking for...

Comment: @Theo Z sorry about that, messed up my formatting. But you've got the idea, that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id 
 FROM `table`
INNER JOIN
 `table` AS table2
 ON table.column1=table2.column1

is probably the nearest you are going to get then you just use a WHERE clause such as 
WHERE table.column1='ab'